# local polynomial regression standard errors

Tags: regression, smoothing, kernel-smoothing, loess

I am attempting to find a reference which explains how one computes standard errors for local polynomial regression? Specifically, in R one can use the `loess` function to get a model object and then use the `predict` function to retrieve standard errors.  Is there a reference somewhere to what is actually happening? What about in the case when there may be serial correlation in the residuals, one must adjust this using Newey-West type methods, is there a way to use the `sandwich` package to do this as you would for a regular OLS using `lm`?